# Mismatch of table numbering

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions

I write my thesis now and it contains many sections and subsections. And I encountered a problem with table numbering. I wrote the simple table like

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My first table}\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and in the text I have reference `\ref{table1}`, but at the end (in .pdf) I get caption **Table 1.1: My first table**, but in text this table has numbering **1.0.** And next table in the this section have caption with **Table 1.2**, but in text it is **1.1**. At the same time I do not have any problem with `figure`, `equation`, `section` etc. numbering.

If someone have the same problem and know the solution of it I will be very happy!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is strange behaviour, provided that you use the same snippet for each table. Are you sure that you use the `\label` AFTER `\caption` in the tables in question?

Comment: have your run latex enough times for the cross referencing to converge? (with no example it's hard to suggest anything else) unrelated but it's not usually a good idea to use labels with numbers like `table1` as it is confusing when the table is numbered with a different number

Comment: Also: You should not specify `[h]` as the only placement method for floats. This way you could get pretty bad placement with large floats. You should always give more than just one option (with the first option the most desirable). So you should change to `[htbp]` or similar. Also, if you tend to use the same option on every float, you might as well just change the default placement.

Answer (score 3):

This is more extended comment ...

- your question is not clear
- from code snippets in question and your answer (which should be moved to question) is not possible reproduce your problem
- in question you show that table numbering is **Table 1.1** etc. This means, that somewhere in your real document you redefine table numbering. Probably with

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
```

- what you really have in included files is not known. is there beside text of section some formatting commands?
- try the following MWE. It is based on some guessing and usual standard document structure:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}                    % added
    \numberwithin{table}{section}           % added
    \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}  % added

    \usepackage{graphicx, floatrow}
    \usepackage[dvips]{xcolor}              % changed
    \usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}   % changed

    \usepackage{lipsum}                     % added for emulating of real text

    \begin{document}
    %\include{section-1}% example its content is: 
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \section{first}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{My first table.}\label{table:line-1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    bla & bla & bla \\
    bla & bla & bla \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[11]

    %\include{section-2}% example its content is: 
    \section{second}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{My second table.}\label{table:line-2}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    bla & bla & bla \\
    bla & bla & bla \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{My third table.}\label{table:line-3}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    bla & bla & bla \\
    bla & bla & bla \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    Test of referencing: see table \ref{table:line-1}, \ref{table:line-2} and \ref{table:line-3}
    \end{document}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

- as you can see, numbering of tables as well their referencing is as expected
- please, consider all comments below your question and try to complete your question that provided MWE will show your problems.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lGR7.png
```

Comment: I would upvote ... but you demanded to refrain from it ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I like to encourage OP to complete her question, but all in answer is not possible to write in comment :). As her question is, it is not possible to help her. Unfortunately. However, I can't (and not willing) to complain if you (or anyone) will not consider my wish regarding voting my answer ...

Comment: Unlike the other post **your** one is an answer and deserves appreciation